# If-Then-Else regex statement

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I am trying to form a regular expression that would capture `<expression1>` if it is in the string otherwise capture `<expression2>`.

I tried something along the lines of: `(IF)(?(1)THEN|ELSE)`, meaning the capture would be `IFTHEN` (in case `IF` is found) or `ELSE` (in case `IF` is not found)

For example:

```
(apple1\d)(?(1)|apple2\d)
```

case1:
for the string: `pear33 apple14 apple24 orange22 orange44`

Result would be: `apple14`

case2:
In contrast for the string: `pear33 apple24 orange22 orange44`

The result would be: `apple24`
(since there is no `apple1` it would capture `apple2\d`)

My regex works well for case1 it returns `apple14` however the `ELSE` doesn't work. I expect it to return `apple24` for case2

Comment: What is your expected output for `pear33 apple24 apple14 orange22 orange44` (changed the `14` and `24`)?

Comment: Your `(IF)` is obligatory. Add `?` after it. However, it seems you need a different regex to solve the real problem. Use 2 regexps, only run the second if the first fails.

Comment: The IF/ELSE is just adding patterns to the regexp. If the capture doesn't match anything, the whole regexp won't match. You should use a lookahead as the IF.

Comment: @a_guest expected value is  apple14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, I'm not sure why you'd need an if-else statement for this (See version 2 of my answer), but I'll try to provide a few solutions.

So, for me, @Barmer's solution ([If-Then-Else regex statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768087/if-then-else-regex-statement/55768282#55768282)) gave me `error: bad character in group name` although I'm sure with proper tweaking that may be the optimal solution.

Until he gets back, however, you can try these (although search.group() and search.groups() do annoy me a bit regarding their handling of capture groups/lack thereof)

.

**VERSION 1: Ultra specific version, based on the solutions suggested above. My solution here is not desirable in my opinion.**

```
>>> import re


>>> string1 = 'pear33 apple14 apple24 orange22 orange44'
>>> string2 = 'pear33 apple24 apple14 orange22 orange44'


>>> re.findall('(?<!apple[12]\d)[\s]+(apple1\d|apple2\d)', string1)
['apple14']
>>> re.findall('(?<!apple[12]\d)[\s]+(apple1\d|apple2\d)', string2)
['apple24']


>>> re.search('(?<!apple[12]\d)[\s]+(apple1\d|apple2\d)', string1).group()
' apple14'
>>> re.search('(?<!apple[12]\d)[\s]+(apple1\d|apple2\d)', string2).group()
' apple24'
```

**VERSIONS 2 AND 3: Way better and more scalable versions in my opinion. I'm privy to version 2. TBH, though, this solution can lead to memory tie ups, but for short strings it will work fine**

```
>>> string1 = 'pear33 apple14 apple24 orange22 orange44'
>>> string2 = 'pear33 apple24 apple14 orange22 orange44'


>>> re.findall('[\S\s]*?(apple[\d]+)[\S\s]*', string1)
['apple14']
>>> re.findall('[\S\s]*?(apple[\d]+)[\S\s]*', string2)
['apple24']


>>> re.findall('(?<!apple\d\d)[\S\s]+?(apple[\d]+)[\S\s]*', string1)
['apple14']
>>> re.findall('(?<!apple\d\d)[\S\s]+?(apple[\d]+)[\S\s]*', string2)
['apple24']
```

Comment: According to OP's comment both examples should return `apple14`. The error you obtained is because (most likely) it should be `(?:...)` in the regex, i.e. missing `:`.

Comment: @a_guest Indeed, but interestingly, he got a +1 and a correct answer with just that post. I'm not sure how, so I'm wondering how it works too.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
(?(?=apple1\d)apple1\d|apple2\d)
```

The `IF` part should be a lookahead, so it's not included in the match requirement when the `ELSE` branch is taken.

If you don't want to repeat the `IF` expression in `THEN`, you can use a backreference.

```
(?(?=(apple1\d))\1|apple2\d)
```

Comment: Whenever I try this I get `error: bad character in group name`

Comment: Could you explain how to use this regex in Python in order to obtain the desired results?

Comment: Even though it didn't completely solve the issue, it was good guidance, I ended up using apple1\d(?=.+apple2)|apple2\d    probably there are better ways to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: used search() instead of findall()

second example:

```
# with "if then else" in search string
string = 'pear33 if then else apple14'
match = re.search(r'if then|else', string)
print(match.group())
```

output:

```
if then
```

no "if" in search string

```
string = 'pear33  then else apple14'
match = re.search(r'if then|else', string)
print(match.group())
```

output:

```
else
```

for first example

```
import re 
string = 'pear33  apple24 orange22 orange44'
match = re.findall(r'(apple1\d|apple2\d)', string)
print(match)
```

output:

```
['apple24']
```